# Python conda error when try to download spacy model

Tags: python, pip, conda, spacy, python-typing

When I try to download a spacy model ("python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm" from conda console) I got the error from below; I think its a problem with typing (typing_extensions) package, but I can't get it what is wrong.

Spacy package  version is 3.7.2; typing_extensions package  version is 4.9.0; typing package version is  3.7.4.3

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 185, in _run_module_as_main
    mod_name, mod_spec, code = _get_module_details(mod_name, _Error)
  File "D:\anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 144, in _get_module_details
    return _get_module_details(pkg_main_name, error)
  File "D:\anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 111, in _get_module_details
    __import__(pkg_name)
  File "D:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spacy\__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    from . import pipeline  # noqa: F401
  File "D:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spacy\pipeline\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .attributeruler import AttributeRuler
  File "D:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spacy\pipeline\attributeruler.py", line 8, in <module>
    from ..language import Language
  File "D:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spacy\language.py", line 43, in <module>
    from .pipe_analysis import analyze_pipes, print_pipe_analysis, validate_attrs
  File "D:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spacy\pipe_analysis.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .tokens import Doc, Span, Token
  File "D:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spacy\tokens\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from ._serialize import DocBin
  File "D:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spacy\tokens\_serialize.py", line 14, in <module>
    from ..vocab import Vocab
  File "spacy\vocab.pyx", line 1, in init spacy.vocab
  File "spacy\tokens\doc.pyx", line 49, in init spacy.tokens.doc
  File "D:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spacy\schemas.py", line 287, in <module>
    class TokenPattern(BaseModel):
  File "pydantic\main.py", line 299, in pydantic.main.ModelMetaclass.__new__
  File "pydantic\fields.py", line 411, in pydantic.fields.ModelField.infer
  File "pydantic\fields.py", line 342, in pydantic.fields.ModelField.__init__
  File "pydantic\fields.py", line 451, in pydantic.fields.ModelField.prepare
  File "pydantic\fields.py", line 545, in pydantic.fields.ModelField._type_analysis
  File "pydantic\fields.py", line 550, in pydantic.fields.ModelField._type_analysis
  File "D:\anaconda3\lib\typing.py", line 774, in __subclasscheck__
    return issubclass(cls, self.__origin__)
TypeError: issubclass() arg 1 must be a class
```

I tried to upgrade spacy (pip install --upgrade spacy), typing, typing_extensions packages

Comment: is this your full traceback error?

Comment: @Goku-standswithPalestine yes; it occur when execute "python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm" on anaconda prompt (windows cmd)

Comment: What is your python version? Also I'm not sure why you have pip and conda tagged

Comment: Anaconda **base** + `pip install` turns a mogwai into gremlins.